# How to move index/position of an item in an array and shuffle others accordingly?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I was wondering if someone could explain how to move items in an array around in Ruby?

e.g

array = [a,b,c,d,e,f,l]

then becomes

array = [b,c,d,e,f,a,l]

I want to move "a" to where "f" is, but I do not want to switch them. I want to move "a" to that position and have "f" and all before it move down the array while the items before it such as "l" stays where they are. In this particular scenario duplicates do not exist. Additionally there is no need for keeping a copy of the original array unchanged.

*tidied up for clarification

Comment: Do you want to always move the first element to a specific position (second last in this example)? Or do you always want to move a specific element (that equals `a`) move to the position of an element that equals `f`?

Comment: It would be interesting to know both, but first element to a specific position is enough.

Comment: When you are asked for clarification it is much better to edit your question than to elaborate in comments. Might you also want to know how to "move", say, `"c"` so that it follows `"f"`? If so, what if the array contains two `"c"`'s? Do you want to modify your array in place or do you want to create a new array with the desired ordering and leave the original array unchanged. You need to state your question in such a way that all these questions--and any others you can think of--are answered. The ability to state code requirements precisely is of crucial importance in your profession.

Comment: Readers may want to cut and paste your code so write `array = [a,b,c,d,e,f,l]` without the "e.g." preface. It is good that you included the local variable `array`, which is omitted in many SO questions. Assigning a variable to each of an examples inputs allows readers to refer to those variables in comments and answers. Also, `=> array [b,c,d,e, f , a ,l]` makes no sense. If` you mean you want `array` to be modified to equal `[b,c,d,e, f , a ,l]`, say that in words.

Comment: The type of manipulation you describe is more often expressed in terms of indices; for example, "I wish to modify the array `array` so that the element at index `i` is moved to index `j` and the order of all other elements is unchanged."

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will use this to better structure my questions in the future, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to insert before the "l", which is position 6.

```
array = ["a", "b" ,"c", "d", "e", "f", "l"]
array.insert(5,array.shift)
=> ["b" ,"c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "l"]
```

Note that we specified position 5 because once the first element is removed (`array.shift`) the new numbering has "l" in position 5 (where formerly it was position 6).

If you did this in separate steps...

```
array = ["a", "b" ,"c", "d", "e", "f", "l"]
character_to_shift = array.shift # shift method removes and returns first entry in array
=> "a"
p array
=> ["b" ,"c", "d", "e", "f", "l"]
p.insert(5, character_to_shift) # insert inserts specified character at index position
    => ["b" ,"c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "l"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by deleting `'a'` out of the array and insert it back in at the index of `'f'` + 1. Keep in mind that order of the code below is important since indexes shift after deleting an item.

```
array   = %w[a b c d e f l]
deleted = array.delete('a') # returns nil if not found
index   = array.index('f')  # returns nil if not found
array.insert(index + 1, deleted)
#=> ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "a", "l"]
```

If you'd change this to a one-liner you get a wrong result.

```
array.insert(array.index('f') + 1, array.delete('a'))
#=> ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "l", "a"]
#                                   ^ 'a' is placed one position to far
```

The reason this happens is because the order of execution is *index* -> (addition of index) -> *delete* -> *insert*. This can be fixed by removing the `+ 1`. However this does only account for the case that `'f'` is present after `'a'`.

```
array = %w[f b c d e a l]
array.insert(array.index('f'), array.delete('a'))
#=> ["a", "f", "b", "c", "d", "e", "l"]
#     ^ 'a' is placed before 'f' (+ 1 is needed here)
```

Furthermore you would also have issues if one of the elements is not found since the result of *index* or *delete* might be `nil`. Doing this multiline allows you to handle exceptions by returning your method early.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain it to me.

Comment: What if the array were `%w[a b a c d e f l]`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland Then it would delete both `'a'`s and add one after the first `'f'`.

Comment: That was my point. The OP says nothing about duplicate values, but if one `"a"` is to be "moved" it's a stretch to assume all other `"a"`'s should be deleted. The question certainly needs to be clarified.

Comment: @CarySwoveland It's possible to overcomplicate every question. In the provided scenario there are no duplicates. The same issue is present for the excepted answer. Who says that `'a'` is always on the first position?

Comment: 1. I disagree. A significant proportion of SO are unambiguous. We should do what we can to boost that percentage. 2&3 We can rarely draw conclusions from examples or from the placement of the green checkmark when the SO is a newbie. 4. No one, which is but one problem with the question. I merely advise getting clarification before answering or stating your assumptions about what is being asked.

Comment: Sorry I have only logged into my account now. Yes in this particular scenario there are no duplicates, but of course it is worth thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

This solves your request for:

> "first element to a specific position"

```
def move_first_element(a, x)
  first = a.shift
  a.insert(x, first)
end
```

if you run this:

```
(0..6).each do |i|
  a = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6]
  move_first_element(a, i)
  puts "First element to index: #{i}"
  puts "#{a}"
end
```

the results are:

```
First element to index: 0
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
First element to index: 1
[1, 0, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
First element to index: 2
[1, 2, 0, 3, 4, 5, 6]
First element to index: 3
[1, 2, 3, 0, 4, 5, 6]
First element to index: 4
[1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 5, 6]
First element to index: 5
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 6]
First element to index: 6
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0]
```